# how to do automatic insert default value or update ignore in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

I got a problem that use Upsert operation.

i have two date fields in the table,"created" and "updated",i use update operation that do INSERT operation when one record doesn't exist,otherwise do UPDATE operation.

when first time insert,the "created" field and "update" field both automatic set current date,when next time update,"the created" field ignore,update "update" field.

but i can't in one statement do that.Here is my code:

```
colls.Update(Query.EQ("_id", page.Id),
             Update.Set("created", page.Created)//in here,how to??
                   .Set("updated", page.LastUpdated)
                   .Inc("freq", 1), UpdateFlags.Upsert, SafeMode.False);
```

my serialize code:

```
cm.MapProperty<DateTime>(c => c.Created).SetElementName("created")
                    .SetSerializationOptions(datetimeSerializationOptions)
                    .SetDefaultValue(DateTime.Now);

cm.MapProperty<DateTime>(c => c.LastUpdated).SetElementName("updated")
                    .SetSerializationOptions(datetimeSerializationOptions);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently mongodb doesn't support "upsert"s which behaves differently if its an insert or an update. but its on their plan in [jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-340). So eigther you do a check if the record exists before deciding on insert or update (simply use multi query); or wait for the new version of mongodb.